# Passing params to c# WebMethod from PHP/SOAP

Tags: asmx, webmethod

I've seen other posts about this but nothing works for me.
Parameters are always null.
Using php soap to call a c# web service (asmx) always results in null values from the service.
Please help! Driving me insane.

```
[WebMethod]
public string CreateContact(string param1, string param2)      
{
    return param1 + "-" + param2; 
}

$client = new SoapClient('https://etc....?wsdl');
$params = array('param1' => 'abc','param2' => 'xyz');
$result = $client->CreateContact($params);
echo $result->CreateContactResult;
```

I've tried var_dump also

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do ...

If that is PHP ... you've got multiple errors.

Try this:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl');
    $params = array('param1' => 'abc','param2' => 'xyz');
    try{
        $result = $client->CreateContact($params);
        echo $result->CreateContactResult;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Should return you the error:

> Function ("CreateContact") is not a valid method for this service

Valid methods for SoapClient you can find here:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Regards,

Łukasz Konkol

Comment: Hi. My example just shows a snippet of the webmethod and then the php below is how iam calling the webservice. They are in separate files. I tried your example but no values are returned and no errors

Comment: Ah i just tried with your webservice url instead of mine. I do get the error you posted. But how does that help me?

Comment: I don't know what want to do ... You example doesn't work at all. You are trying to call CreateContact function from SoapClient object. This function doesn't exists. I have no idea what you want to do :)